# JProfiler: remote connect to non standard user

Tags: remote-debugging, jprofiler

I am trying JProfiler and need to connect via ssh to running JVMs in our prod system. The JVMs are started with a special user that doesn't have his home directory in `/home` but `/var/opt/<username>`. I added a `.ssh` folder and my public key. Now connecting with JProfiler does the authentication, but immediatly after throws a java `RuntimeException`:

> net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPExcetion: No such file or directory

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include the stack trace of the exception

Comment: Well there was no "get  details" button. I however started another instance of the service with the agendpath. This does the job.

Comment: I run jProfiler on windows (so no systemd). I really don't know where to search for the stacktrace.

Comment: Please check the file %TEMP%/jprofiler_error.log, if it exists, it should show the stack trace.